# Verify data exists before generating PDF with Grails controller

Tags: pdf, grails, render

I am not using the PDF plugin. I am just using the Java API for Jasper. Everything is working fine. The PDF opens in a separate window. The issue that I'm having is when there is no data found, it still opens to a blank tab in the browser. I am trying to intercept this and show a message instead that there is no data, but nothing I've tried is working.

Here is a code snippet from the controller:

```
projAccomps = projAccomps.findAll { ProjectAccomplishment pa ->
    pa.workDate >= startDate && pa.workDate <= endDate
}

// I'd like to be able to check right here for no data
// and send back a message instead
// 
// if (projAccomps.size() < 1) ...

JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(projAccomps)

String jasperFile =
        grailsApplication.mainContext
                .getResource('reports/accomplishment-listing.jasper')
                .file
                .getAbsoluteFile()

// Report parameter
Map<String, String> reportParam = new HashMap<String, String>()

String projectQuery = "All projects"
String dateRange = ""
Boolean allProjects = true
if (params.project) {
    projectQuery = project.name
    allProjects = false
}
if (params.startDate) {
    dateRange = startDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy')
}
if (params.endDate) {
    dateRange += " - " + endDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy')
}

String reportCriteria = "Work Order: ${wo.workOrderNumber}, Project(s): ${projectQuery}, Dates: ${dateRange}"
reportParam['report_criteria'] = reportCriteria
reportParam['all_projects'] = allProjects

JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperFile, reportParam, ds );

byte[] bytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print)

render(file: bytes, contentType: 'application/pdf')
```

I've tried Jquery.ajax and tried to grab the PDF data or a message in the success function, but that was a disaster.

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Is the above called via ajax?

Answer (score 1):

In a controller action there are several ways to create a response, for example redirect or render, in the case you expose it makes sense to use a redirect and then a return

I think this should work

```
// ... get projAccomps data

if (!projAccomps) {
    flash.message "No result between $startDate and $endDate"

    redirect uri: '/some/url'
    return
}

// ... render pdf logic
```

There is a library that you can create pdf or word documents using builders, I share the link, if you want to try alternatives to jasper

https://github.com/craigburke/document-builder

Comment: This does work except for the fact that the form submitting the parameters has a target="_blank" which causes a new tab / window to open immediately. This is a requirement. Also, I have a lot of ajax on this page and would have liked for the 'empty' message to just have appeared somewhere on the page similar to a flash.message, but not being able to grab the PDF data in a 'success' function and then somehow render it is making this difficult.